# ratio of rows that have certain value in a given column to the total number of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

Assume I have a table as follow:

```
product feat1 value 
A       1    2
A       2    0
A       3    3
A       4    0
B       1    1
B       2    0
C       1    1
C       2    2
C       3    4
```

I am trying to find the ratio of zero in each product, so for example the output would be:

```
product ratio
  A      0.5
  B      0.5
  C      0
```

For whatever reason I cannot make this to work, here is what I have done:

```
select product, count(*) from Table where value=0 group by product
```

This gives me the number of rows where there is a zero in product, however this does not include C as it does not have zero to begin with. I also do not know how to include the ratio into place. I was thinking to do it with case statement but still could not make it to work with group by. I was thinking to do it with common table expression for the ratio, but I think I am over complicating the problem.

Comment: I removed the <ansi-sql> tag since the accepted answer isn't ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AVG()` aggregate function over the boolean expression `value = 0`:

```
SELECT product,
       AVG(value = 0) AS ratio
FROM tablename
GROUP BY product;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/w0Ysqyw3).

Comment: This gives an error invalid function type AVG for type Boolean, any clue why this is the case.

Comment: @user59419 then you are not using MySql.

Comment: Sorry, I think it is ANSI SQL, I changed the tag.

Comment: @user59419 ANSI SQL is just a specification. Most databases comply to this specification but use their own dialect which you should know. Anyway, in standard SQL, you can use `AVG(CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` instead of `AVG(value = 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `group by` and `sum(value=0)/count(1)`

```
select product, sum(value=0)/count(1) as ratio
from mytable
group by product
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/OZHX0WX_)

Comment: This gives an error invalid function type SUM for type Boolean, any clue why this is the case.